# 'enableDefaultTyping(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping)' is deprecated in RedisConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

What is the alternative of enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL) is **deprecated in RedisConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        // redis serialize
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);
        StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate(factory);
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/jackson-user@googlegroups.com/msg01557.html may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
om.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance,ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).